# How can I achieve a bullet tracing effect similar to the one in Planetside?

Tags: 3d, first-person-shooter

I've noticed that bullet tracers in Planetside 2 don't show up close -- every time I see them, it came from a barrel a ways away. I don't believe Planetside traces every bullet either, because then it'd look really weird.

I'm not sure what the exact parameters are, so how can I achieve a similar affect?

Comment: Questions about how a specific game implemented a feature only invites speculation. If you want to implement something similar yourself, tell us what you've tried so far and what about it isn't working.

Comment: "I think questions in the form of: "How can I achieve a similar effect as in Game X" are way better " Linked in the help center.

Comment: Could you describe the effect a little more otherwise it is hard to answer unless you have played planetside

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**[referencing a video clip here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onHTvL1rqRI)** i imagine there are a few things going on:

- not every bullet is being drawn with a "tracer" - just like you said

in theory i think you could accomplish this effect rather simply,  when firing bullets you could create every Nth bullet with a different type.  you can have the visual appearance of that bullet be an illuminated tracer whether using some form of shader or particle effect to draw a glow or animated "trail".

[there is also a similar question related to machine gun tracer rounds in unity, if you are up for additional reading](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/38121/bullet-tracer-for-machine-gun.html)

---

- to actually see the tracer rounds, you need to be far from them

this could be accomplished by setting some sort of minimum view distance logic on the visual appearance of the bullets themselves. (or even from their source)

food for thought: this also leaves the possibility for a separate appearance for rounds fired at any given time of day / night.  and additionally an alternative appearance for rounds fired "near" the player, if you wanted to use more detailed textures and effects when the player is nearby